# Ubuntu 13.04 tells me it won't update itself anymore, wants me to upgrade to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, updates

My girlfriend was using my Ubuntu 13.04, when the software update window opened, with an alert box reading something like:

```
Ubuntu 13.04 updates are not provided anymore, for your security 
you should upgrade to 13.10.
```

I didn't think of making a screen capture because my girlfriend was in a time crunch,
but it happened a few days ago (02-19-2014), and I have not received system updates since.

I thought .04s where long term releases, it hasn't been out for a year yet. What's happening?

Anyone else saw that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ubuntu 13.04 updates are not provided anymore, for your security 
>   you should upgrade to 13.10.

Ubuntu 13.04 already reached EOL(End of life).So you won't get any  upgrades for this version.Try to upgrade your pc from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10.

And all Ubuntu versions ending in .04 are not LTS versions.

[LTS Versions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

[EOL releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thanks to your EOL intel, I found this page: http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Comment: I'll just wait for 14.04, which is a LTR.